Show earth view(sphere) with markers and polylines
I want to show earth view in my application. On that earth view I want to show two markers and draw a poly line between two markers.
Some of the poly line is normal poly line and some is dotted poly line.
I am attaching the image. I need that type of functionality.
Earth View
Any help would be appreciated.

Yes, you can use MapBox SDK in your Android Application.
click this link for more information Click here
